# Problem with Wireless Driver of Lenovo T540p Laptop

Tags: wireless, lenovo, realtek

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 to my laptop. However, there is no WiFi interface. I tried  Realtek drivers but they did not work. They made kernel crash at boot phase and the system could not become up.

Here is output of `lspci` command:

```
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem via installing the kernel 3.16.3 manually.

## Download linux-headers-3.16.3-031603-generic_3.16.3-031603.201409171435_amd64.deb, linux-headers-3.16.3-031603_3.16.3-031603.201409171435_all.deb, and linux-image-3.16.3-031603-generic_3.16.3-031603.201409171435_amd64.deb files from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.16.3-utopic.

## sudo dpkg --install linux-headers-3.16*.deb linux-image-3.16*.deb

## sudo reboot

PS: I know wget command but askubuntu does not let me post 2 links now.